# Functor over multiple levels

Tags: list, function, haskell, functional-programming, functor

I have this lame attempt:

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f f2 = (fmap2 f . fmap f2)
```

It is supposed to work like this:

```
fmap2 negate [[1,2], [3]] -- Returns [[-1,-2],[-3]]
fmap2 head [Just "abc",Nothing,Just "def"] -- Returns [Just 'a',Nothing,Just 'e']
```

Note, that this is an exercise. (I gave it a try for like 1,5 hours, yet did not found any solution.)

Q: What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Write down all the types for the variables at hand. It's easier if you don't take `f2` as input, IMO, and think of `fmap2` as something that turns `h :: a->b` into `?? :: f (g a) -> f (g b)`. Well, take `h` then as single argument. What is the type of `fmap h`? How to obtained the wanted `??` from that?

Answer (score 5):

When you get stuck in something like this, I'd recommend using type holes as they drive you in the right direction

```hs
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f nested_functor = fmap _something nested_functor 
--      |                |    |- notice this underscore
--      |                |- clearly we need to fmap something over the nested_functor but we don't know what yet
--      |- Using better names usually helps. Haskellers tend to use very short names, but that's not appropriate always
```

If you try to compile this code, `ghc` will notice the `_something` and will propose you a type for it

```
Found hole: _something :: g a -> g b <-- This is interesting
      Where: ‘a’, ‘g’, ‘b’ ... (blah blah blah, not interesting)
      Or perhaps ‘_something’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
```

We know that `_something` needs to have type `g a -> g b` given `Functor g`. Hence:

```hs
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f nested_functor = fmap something nested_functor
  where 
    -- remember something :: Functor g => g a -> g b
    something = undefined -- left as an exercise
```

Comment: I still don’t get it.

Comment: @coderodde That's not a productive followup. Unless you go into more detail about what you do and don't understand, nobody can clarify the parts you don't understand.

Comment: @coderodde. In your problem there are three "object" you can use: `f`, `nested_functor` and `fmap` comming from the `Functor g` constraint. Therefore, there are a very limite combination of things you can try for `something`. `f nested_functor` or `f fmap` or `nested_functor fmap` or `nested_functor f` or `fmap f` or `fmap nested functor` or the combination involving all three of them. Amongs these combs only one makes sense/compile

Answer (score 1):

You should `fmap` with a functor mapping as function for the inner structure, so something like:

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f = fmap (fmap …)
```

where I leave filling in the `…` part as an exercise.

Comment: I still don’t get it.

Answer (score 0):

When used in this

```
fmap2 head [Just "abc",Nothing,Just "def"] -- Returns [Just 'a',Nothing,Just 'e']
```

- what type is `head`? It's `[Char] -> Char`¹;
- and what type is `[Just "abc",Nothing,Just "def"]`? It's `[Maybe [Char]]`.

So you have a function `[Char] -> Char` and you want to apply it to the `[Char]`s that is inside a `Maybe` functor, that is in turn inside a `[]` functor.

One `fmap` allows you to go through one of those layers, so you need 2 to go through 2. Look:

```hs
           head  $       "abc"                     ==       'a'
      fmap head  $  Just "abc"                     ==  Just 'a'
      fmap head  $             Nothing             ==           Nothing
fmap (fmap head) $ [Just "abc",Nothing,Just "def"] == [Just 'a',Nothing,Just 'e']
```

---

Yes, `head` is a polymorphic `[a] -> a`, but in the case above it's operating on `[Char]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Test.QuickCheck

fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 = fmap . fmap

prop_negate :: Property
prop_negate = property (fmap2 negate [[1,2],[3]] == [[-1,-2],[-3]])

prop_head :: Property
prop_head = property (fmap2 head [Just "abc", Nothing, Just "def"]
                              == [Just 'a', Nothing, Just 'd'])
```

So let's look at the two versions side by side:

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f f2 = (fmap2 f . fmap f2)
```

and

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 = fmap . fmap
-- or
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 fab fga = (fmap . fmap) fab fga
```

In the first version, you reference `fmap2` within `fmap2` making it recursive.  I don't think you meant to do that.  The nested functors are not a case of recursion, as the second test case makes clear with the `Maybe` functor inside a list functor -- definitely not a recursive repetition.

The next issue is with the two parameters given to `fmap2`.  In the type signature the two parameters are correctly identified as 1) a function `a -> b` and 2) a nested functor, functor of type 'g' inside functor of type 'f'.  Here the two parameters are very different -- a function to be applied to a nested functor and the nested functor itself.  In the function binding (`fmap2 f f2 = (fmap2 f . fmap2 f2)`) it seems like the two parameters are supposed to be symmetrical -- taking the same place as a first parameter -- but as we just saw in the type signature they are two different things: a function and a functor, so clearly they cannot be used symmetrically.  Either you are considering these two different things as two functions or two functors.  I suspect you are thinking of the two functors (type f and type g).  It seems like you are trying to `fmap` over the two nested functors separately here.  As you will see, the two functors are supposed to be mapped over together.

The second version is written in two forms.  In the first form, the "point-free" way of writing it, `fmap2` is given simply as the composition of `fmap` twice.  Since we want to apply a function `a -> b` to values of type 'a' inside two nested functors, the composition of `fmap` twice jumps over the first functor (type f) then the second functor (type g) to get to the value(s) of type 'a' and apply the transformation function.

In the second form of the second version, the parameters are explicitly given.  (They are merely implied in the point-free version, which should be easy to see.) This should help to clarify the mistaken parameters in the first version.  The transformation function `fab` and the nested functors `fga` play different roles. The double `fmap` digs down twice into `fga` to get to the values of type 'a' and apply the function `fab` (`a -> b`).

The structure of nested functors, the 'fg' part of `fga`, is thus preserved but the value(s) of type 'a' can be transformed into values of type 'b' (not necessarily different in the case of `negate`, but possibly so, as in the case of `head` which takes, in our example, a string and returns a character). In this way the function of type `a -> b` applied to the nested functors `(f (g a))` will produce the same nested functors with (potentially) different values inside, `(f (g b))` which is what the compiler expects from the type signature.